Does "by the time" mandate perfect constructions?
Consider this sentence:

I'm planning to do it by the time she comes.

I think that that is wrong and that I need to say:

I'm planning to have done it by the time she comes.

Am I right?
I think so because I was taught that I have to use perfect tenses before by the time.

No, either of these is acceptable and common

(2) emphasises that the task will be finished before she arrives, but in practice both mean the same.

In fact, in context, they can both be used but in any case, they are both grammatical. Two roommates are talking: John: You really need to tidy up your room. Mark: I'm planning to do it by the time Mary arrives.

You've misinterpreted the rule. In a situation where someone does A before B, you would indeed use the perfect for A:

He had cooked dinner by the time she came.

Or in present tense (less natural but might use it e.g. when describing the plot of a movie):

He has cooked dinner by the time she comes.

Or even in future:

He will have cooked dinner by the time she comes.

Maybe there are exceptions, but it's a good general rule to say "use the perfect before by the time..." in such cases.
But your example is more complex so the rule doesn't apply. In my examples above there are two times, A and B, and two finite verbs "had cooked" and "came". In your case there are three points in time and three verbs. In

He is planning to cook dinner by the time she comes.

you have the time he makes the plan (A), the time he cooks dinner (B), and the time she comes (C). "By the time" expresses a relationship between B and C. But B is expressed in the infinitive after "to plan". So you don't need to make it perfect.
A more accurate rule would be: use the perfect tense for the verb before by the time when both verbs are finite.

thank you it makes things more clear. Since, I saw your examples I thinl you saw my other question about continuous tenses and "by the time". Could you comment on that too?
